# UICollectionView Footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to add footer to the UICollectionView.

Following is my code,

UICollectionView is added through IB

IN viewDidLoad I register the footer,

```
[mCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footer"];
```

And implemented following method

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
      UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [mCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"footer" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      [headerView addSubview:mFooterView];
      reusableview = headerView;
   }
   return reusableview;
}
```

But My application keep crashing and below is the log,

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionView.m:2249

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your code why you are dequeing a header view and adding the footer to it ?

the normal implementation of this method is :

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath 
{

   UICollectionReusableView *theView;

   if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
   {
      theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
   } else {
      theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footer" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
   }

   return theView;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same things and It worked for me!!I will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var myView = UICollectionReusableView()
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            myView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: myHeader, for: indexPath)
        } else {
            myView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: myFooter, for: indexPath)
        }
            return myView
        }
```